# Conceito Envolvido no uso de Knex aninhado

Tags: node.js, knex.js

Em minhas programações em Node.JS fiz um código que funcionou, mas quero entender o conceito desse funcionamento.

No código em questão uso o knex para recuperar informações de uma base de dados MySQL.. para tal importo o módulo do knex:

```
const config = {...}
const knex = require('knex')(config)
```

Até aí nada novo, só que dessa vez eu precisei fazer um consulta aninhada e foi a primeira vez. No caso eu consultei os dados de uma venda e em seguida os itens da venda. Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
const getSales = async () => {
    await knex("tbl_vendas")
        .select(knex.raw("tbl_vendas.id_vendas, tbl_vendedores.nome AS vendedor, " +
            "tbl_clientes.nome_razaosocial AS cliente, tbl_vendas.data, tbl_vendas.hora, " +
            "tbl_vendas.cupom, tbl_vendas.total"))
        .leftOuterJoin("tbl_vendedores", "tbl_vendedores.id_vendedores", "tbl_vendas.id_vendedores")
        .leftOuterJoin("tbl_clientes", "tbl_clientes.id_clientes", "tbl_vendas.id_clientes")
        .then(sales => {
            const rows = sales.map(sale => {
                return knex("tbl_vendas_itens")
                    .select("tbl_vendas_itens.id_vendas_itens AS id_item", "tbl_produtos.descricao",
                        "tbl_vendas_itens.qtde", "tbl_vendas_itens.vl_unitario", "tbl_vendas_itens.desconto",
                        "tbl_vendas_itens.vl_total")
                    .leftOuterJoin("tbl_produtos", "tbl_vendas_itens.id_produtos", "tbl_produtos.id_produtos")
                    .where("tbl_vendas_itens.id_vendas", "=", sale.id_vendas)
                    .then(sales_items => {
                        const newRow = { ...sale, itens: [...sales_items] }
                        return newRow
                    })
            })
            return Promise.all(rows)
        })
        .then(console.log);
}
```

Escrever esse código foi bem intuitivo e deu certo, mas depois fiquei espantado pelo fato de usar a constante **knex** duas vezes, uma dentro da outra e não ter dado problema.

Executei um **console.log(typeof(knex))** para saber do que se tratava e me retornou que é uma **function**.

Alguém poderia me explicar a teoria por trás do uso do **knex dentro do outro** e com isso me ajudar a entender porque não dá erro fazer isso?